# Drop consecutive duplicates which have milliseconds different sampling frequency - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

The dataframe looks like this:

```
0, 3710.968017578125, 2012-01-07T03:13:43.859Z
1, 3710.968017578125, 2012-01-07T03:13:48.890Z
2, 3712.472900390625, 2012-01-07T03:13:53.906Z
3, 3712.472900390625, 2012-01-07T03:13:58.921Z
4, 3713.110107421875, 2012-01-07T03:14:03.900Z
5, 3713.110107421875, 2012-01-07T03:14:03.937Z
6, 3713.89892578125, 2012-01-07T03:14:13.900Z
7, 3713.89892578125, 2012-01-07T03:14:13.968Z
8, 3713.89892578125, 2012-01-07T03:14:19.000Z
9, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:24.000Z
10, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:24.015Z
11, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:29.000Z
12, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:29.031Z
```

At some rows, there are lines with millisecond different timestamps, I want to drop them and only keep the rows that have different second timestamps. there are rows that have the same value for milliseconds and seconds different rows like from row 9 to 12, therefore, I can't use `a.loc[a.shift() != a]`

The desired output would be:

```
0, 3710.968017578125, 2012-01-07T03:13:43.859Z
1, 3710.968017578125, 2012-01-07T03:13:48.890Z
2, 3712.472900390625, 2012-01-07T03:13:53.906Z
3, 3712.472900390625, 2012-01-07T03:13:58.921Z
4, 3713.110107421875, 2012-01-07T03:14:03.900Z
6, 3713.89892578125, 2012-01-07T03:14:13.900Z
8, 3713.89892578125, 2012-01-07T03:14:19.000Z
9, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:24.000Z
11, 3714.64990234375, 2012-01-07T03:14:29.000Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df[2]).astype('datetime64[s]')).head(1)
```

I hope it's self-explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script. I didn't get your dataframe column names so I invented below columns ['x', 'date_time']

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
(3710.968017578125, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:13:43.859Z')),
(3710.968017578125, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:13:48.890Z')),
(3712.472900390625, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:13:53.906Z')),
(3712.472900390625, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:13:58.921Z')),
(3713.110107421875, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:03.900Z')),
(3713.110107421875, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:03.937Z')),
(3713.89892578125, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:13.900Z')),
(3713.89892578125, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:13.968Z')),
(3713.89892578125, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:19.000Z')),
(3714.64990234375, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:24.000Z')),
(3714.64990234375, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:24.015Z')),
(3714.64990234375, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:29.000Z')),
(3714.64990234375, pd.to_datetime('2012-01-07T03:14:29.031Z'))], 
    columns=['x', 'date_time'])
```

- create a column 'time_diff' to get the difference between the
  datetime of current row and next row
- only get those difference either
  None or more than 1 second
- drop temp column time_diff

> ```
> df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('x')['date_time'].diff()
> df = df[(df['time_diff'].isnull()) | (df['time_diff'].map(lambda x: x.seconds > 1))]
> df = df.drop(['time_diff'], axis=1)
> df
> ```